# Issue with Printing Data stored in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm having some issues when I call the print function for a linked list I created. I created three list objects, stored within them the ints 1,2,3 and then when I run the program, the data is printed out, followed by a hexadecimal number. Here is the output:

```
10x47e864
20x47e864
30x47e864

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.026 s
Press any key to continue.
```

---

Here is the .h file:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H


class List
{
    public:
        List();
        void AddNode(int addData);
        void DeleteNode(int delData);
        void PrintList();

    private:
        typedef struct node{
            int data;
            node* next;
        }* nodePtr;

        nodePtr head;
        nodePtr curr;
        nodePtr temp;
};

#endif // LIST_H
```

Here is the .cpp

```
#include "List.h"
#include <cstdlib>//for NULL const
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    List li;

    li.AddNode(1);
    li.AddNode(2);
    li.AddNode(3);
    li.PrintList();
}

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp=NULL;
}

void List::AddNode(int addData){
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next=NULL;
    n->data=addData;

    if(head!=NULL)//if a linked list exists
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next!=NULL){
            //while not at end of list
            curr=curr->next;//advances ptr until last node in list
        }
        curr->next=n;//make n point to last node;
    }

    else{//if list does not exist

        head = n;
    }
}

void List::DeleteNode(int delData){
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr!=NULL && curr->data!= delData){
        //to pass through list
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;//traverse list until delData not found
    }
    if(curr==NULL)//passed through list, delData int not found
    {
        cout<<delData<<" was not in list\n";
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else{
        delPtr = curr;
        curr == curr->next;//patching hole in list
        delete delPtr;
        cout<<"the value "<<delData<<" was deleted\n";
    }
}

void List::PrintList(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        cout<<curr->data<<cout<<endl;
        curr=curr->next;//adv the curr ptr
    }
}
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect `cout` statement in the `PrintList()` remove the second `cout` from this line, i.e, change

```
cout<<curr->data<<cout<<endl;
```

to

```
cout <<  curr->data << endl;
```